# How to return exception for a specific element in list in junit

Tags: java, junit, mocking

Using mockito and powermock in java

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3);
Test mock = mock(Test.class);
when(Mock.method(list)).thenThow(Exception.class); 
// this throw exception for all input value 1,2, and 3
```

Is there a way to mock throw an exception only if list is 2 while 1, 3 do something in method properly?

```
public class Test {
    List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> method(List<Integer> input) {
            ...
            return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the elements inside the list?

Comment: Some context is missing - why would a value of 2 somewhere in a List cause an exception?  Please add more details.

Comment: this should be method logic right ? `throw an exception only if list is 2 while 1, 3 do something in method properly`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `doAnswer()` for this task, like this,
This is the code when you expected the list has 2 then throw exception

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleClassTest {

    private ExampleClass exampleClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        exampleClass = spy(new ExampleClass());
    }

    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void shouldThrowException() {
        // Arrange
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            if (args.length > 0) {
                List<Integer> argList = (List<Integer>) args[0];
                if (argList.contains(2))
                    throw new Exception("invalid inputs");
            }
            return Arrays.asList(1);
        }).when(exampleClass).getString(list);

        // Act
        exampleClass.getString(list);
    }
}
```

, This one if you want specific action in target class when reaching the element 2. just spy the ArrayList

```
    @Test(expected = Exception.class)
    public void shouldThrowException() {
        // Arrange
        List<Integer> list = spy(new ArrayList<>());
        when(list.size()).thenReturn(4);
        when(list.get(0)).thenReturn(1);
        when(list.get(1)).thenReturn(1);
        when(list.get(2)).thenThrow(new Exception());
        when(list.get(3)).thenReturn(3);

        // Act
        exampleClass.getString(list);
    }
}
```